# WP Hotel Booking - ¿Cómo centro los contenidos de cada página single-room? [Solucionada]

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Cuando accedo a cada room sus contenidos aparecen a la izquierda y no centrados.
No veo forma de editar el contenido sin tocar la plantilla.
Sin embargo en la demo del tema aparecen los contenidos mucho mejor presentados que como me los muestra a mi. (Theme Howello)
¿Como puedo configurar los contenidos sin tocar el código de la plantilla?

Entiendo que algo estoy haciendo mal, pero mi última opción sería editar la plantilla. Aunque podría hacerlo.

EDITO: La solución viene de crear un tema hijo que me estropeaba los estilos.
Poniendo el tema padre se ve bien. Por lo tanto la solución es arreglar el CSS del tema hijo.

Comment: Si el theme original no tiene el padding que tiene tu contenido actual, significa que el plugin está añadiendo algo cuando se cumple que estás en un single post. Lo más sano sería crear un Child Theme  para alterar Howello sin tocarlo

Comment: mil gracias!! eso no se me habia ocurrido probarlo.
Al cambiar al tema padre lo muestra bien.
La solución es ver que he hecho en el tema hijo que estropea la forma de mostrar el contenido. Muchas gracias.